# Add custom text to the end of CSV file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, csv, parsing

How to add custom text to the end of .csv file in NodeJS? Currently, I parse csv file and do some validation against predefined parameters (separator, columns number etc.) and after that I have to add custom line at the end of file.

Example:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
Row1 Row1 Row1 Row1
Row2 Row2 Row2 Row2
Row3 Row3 Row3 Row3
```

And at the end, there should be custom line with line ending character.

Ex:

```
this is the end of file\n
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [appendFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback):

```
Asynchronously:

const fs = require('fs');

fs.appendFile('yourfile.csv', 'this is the end of file\n', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});

Synchronously:

const fs = require('fs');

fs.appendFileSync('yourfile.csv', 'this is the end of file\n');
```